# Help with Trie implementation

Tags: c, trie

I have been trying to implement the basic functions of inserting characters into a trie data structure in C. I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but for the last day or so I've been stumped/stuck.

Heres some code I've written up:

```
TR head = NULL;

void initDict () {
  head = NULL;
}

TR newNode (char item) {
  TR temp;
  temp = malloc (sizeof(*temp));
  temp->thisChar = item;
  temp->child = NULL;
  temp->sibling = NULL;
  return temp;
}


TR insertInOrder (char item, TR trie) {
  if (trie == NULL) {
    trie = newNode(item);
  } else if (trie->thisChar < item) {
        insertInOrder(item, trie->sibling);
    } else if (trie->thisChar > item) {
        char temp = trie->thisChar;
        trie->thisChar = item;
        insertInOrder(temp, trie->sibling);
    }
    return trie;
}

void insert (char *word) {
  char letter = *word;
    TR temp = NULL;

    while (*word != '\0') {
        letter = *word;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode(letter);
            temp = head->child;
            word++;
        } else {
            temp = insertInOrder(letter, temp);
            temp->child = head->child;
            head->child = temp;
            word++;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure this out...

P.S checkLetter, is a boolean function that checks if the letter is already inside the trie (through traversing through the trie structure, i.e. trie = trie->sibling)

Any help would be appreciated =]

Cheers!

EDIT: changed my code, so that insertInOrder returns a value, but since insert is a void function and has to stay a void function, I don't know of a way to insert nodes further down into the head of the trie (i.e. head->child, head->child->child etc)

Comment: yeah it compiles, apart from the client, header files and the missing checkLetter function it compiles, but seg faults around the temp = temp->child line in the insert() function

Comment: removed my comment. Just noticed your TR typedef. Don't like it though. Very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-think your insertion algorithm :-)

I am not very good teacher, so I'll just give you the solution without any good motivations. This is not compiled and verified though, think of this as pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I think is a better algorithm that handles some corner cases you seem to have missed, plus uses the 'head' pointer differently to yield a more consistent algorithm:

```
// 'head' is assumed to be a valid pointer, its 'child' field either NULL or a valid 
// pointer
TR currentNode = head;
while ( *word )
{
    assert(currentNode != NULL);

    if ( currentNode->child == NULL || currentNode->child->thisChar < *word )
    {
        // We need to insert a new node first in the child list
        TR newNode = malloc(sizeof *currentNode);
        newNode->thisChar = *word;
        newNode->sibling = currentNode->child;
        newNode->child = NULL;
        currentNode->child = newNode;
        currentNode = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // Find the place to insert next node
        currentNode = currentNode->child;
        while ( currentNode->sibling && currentNode->thisChar < *word )
            currentNode = currentNode->sibling;

        // If the current node already represents current character, we're done
        // Otherwise, insert a new node between the current node and its sibling
        if ( currentNode->thisChar != *word )
        {
            TR newNode = malloc(sizeof *currentNode);
            newNode->thisChar = *word;
            newNode->child = NULL;
            newNode->sibling = currentNode->sibling;
            currentNode->sibling = newNode;
            currentNode = newNode;
        }
    }
    word++;
}
```

Comment: could you explain to me, why `newNode->sibling = currentNode->child` that line confuses me

Comment: The new node is inserted as the child of the current node, so any existing child should be sibling to the new node. (If the current node does not have any child the statement is redundant but harmless)

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your insertInOrder function, you check if you need to allocate a new node. Then you allocate a new node if needed, but you store the address of the new node in a local that goes away as soon as you return.

Feels like maybe the insertInOrder function should return a TR that insert does something good with?

Comment: ok, that was one of the problems, thanks a lot! It seems to be working alright now, but after I return the node, my void insert (has to stay a void), can't seem to store anything onto head->child, i.e. I don't know a way I can keep moving down the trie and creating new nodes for it